# Htaccess rewrite to index.html or admin.html

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, redirect

I use the routing module of AngularJS for my WebApp and it works great. But I want that when the user reload a page like `/Category/1`, he will be redirected to `index.html` with `/Category/1` as parameters. This is working.

But when I want to add an admin interface, it brokes...

Here is my folder :

- index.html
- admin.html
- Some angularjs folders...

And my .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 # Redirect /index.html to / 
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html
    RewriteRule ^index.html/?(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]

 # Run everything that contains /admin/ but real files through admin.html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} .*/admin/.*
    RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin.html/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

 # Run everything else but real files through index.html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

</IfModule>
```

When i go to /admin/Category/1, it tries to access a folder named admin.html/Category/1, and obviously it fails...

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your rules by this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 # Redirect /index.html to / 
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html
    RewriteRule ^index.html(/.*)?$ $1 [R=301,L]

 # Run everything that contains /admin/ but real files through admin.html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /admin/
    RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin.html?$1 [L,QSA]

 # Run everything else but real files through index.html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: It doesn't work... The problem with the `?` instead of the `/` is that AngularJS router doesn't recognize it has an url. So, when I refresh the page, I fallback to /admin.html without the content...

Comment: Urls provided by AngularJS :
 - home: http://www.example.com/
 - category : http://www.example.com/Category/
 - Article 1 in Category : http://www.example.com/Category/1
 - admin : http://www.example.com/admin/
 - category in admin : http://www.example.com/admin/Category
 - Article 1 in Category in Admin : http://www.example.com/admin/Category/1

With your htaccess, when I ask for the Category in Admin, AngularJS send me the admin page only. I think the problem comes from the admin.html**?**$(1)...

Comment: I have the admin.html page without the Category informations

Comment: Ok, your initial solution work ! It was a mistake from my angular app which cause this problem. My mistake, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Urls provided by AngularJS :

- home: http://www.example.com/
- category : http://www.example.com/Category/
- Article 1 in Category : http://www.example.com/Category/1
- admin : http://www.example.com/admin/
- category in admin : http://www.example.com/admin/Category
- Article 1 in Category in Admin : http://www.example.com/admin/Category/1

With your htaccess, when I ask for the Category in Admin, AngularJS send me the admin page only. I think the problem comes from the admin.html**?**$(1)...