# How to link to pages in my single page web app?

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, browser-history

I'm making a single page website that uses the [HTML5 history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to push states when a new part of the site is opened. For example, when someone clicks a link to show the "contact" modal, the site fires:

```
history.pushState( stateObj, "Contact Page", "/contact/");
```

When a user clicks forward or back a `window.onpopstate` function changes the browser to the currently selected page.

What I don't understand is how to deal with inbound links or page refreshes. If someone links to "www.mysite.com/contact/", that page doesn't actually exist so it 404s. Using 301 redirects seems like an ugly, incomplete solution. Is there an easier way to deal with this behavior?

Comment: AngularJS maybe? you can set it up in an hour with your website. It makes single page web apps much easier.

Comment: @Joraid that's a great idea but unfortunately not an option for the site I'm currently working on.

Comment: In our case, with just JS. You need to trigger actions whenever the URL changes. Then remove the HTML portion in your page and replace with the new page based on the URL of the page requested. The process is JS and is done manually.

Comment: You want to remain your page, though user click browser back or forward button, isn't it?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna the site already properly updates states and works with browsers back/forward buttons. I'm just not sure how to deal with specific page lnks.

Comment: Why would there by a link to "www.mysite.com/contact/" if the file does not exist at server?

Comment: @guest271314 an example would be, a user clicks on the "contact" link, the URL gets updated to "www.mysite.com/contact/" via `history.pushState`, then the user copies the URL to share the link with someone else. If someone clicks on that link, the page would not actually exist.

Comment: Have you tried using `ServiceWorker`? Why do you need to change the URL to "www.mysite.com/contact/"? Why do you not use fragment identifiers `"www.mysite.com#contact"`?

Comment: You need the server to send the same page to the user (for client-side rendering) for each URL, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145640/htaccess-rewrite-to-index-html-or-admin-html